# Net profit/loss percentage formula - after fees

Tags: percentages

An asset is bought at price $x$ and sold at a price $y$, increasing or decreasing in value $\frac{y-x}{x}$ percent ($C$). Buying/selling incurs a percentage fee, let's call it $F$. The asset is bought in exchange for "money", let's call it $M$.

To calculate the final profit/loss, one can use the following formula:

$$bought = \frac{M-MF}{x}$$

$$sold = (bought-boughtF)y$$

Because of fees, $\frac{sold - M}{M}$ will always be lower than $C$.

**Example**

Starting with $M=100$, with fees of $1$%, I can buy an asset that costs $x=50$:

$$bought = \frac{100-100*0.01}{50} = 1.98$$

Let's say that later the asset depreciates -10% in price, $y=45$, and it's sold:

$$sold = (1.98-1.98*0.01) * 45 = 88.209$$

The asset only depreciated -10% ($\frac{45-50}{50}$), but with fees, the loss was -11.79% ($\frac{88.209-100}{100}$).

**Question**

Is there a formula I can use to compute the net profit directly? I.e. knowing that the gross depreciation was -10% and there were 2 fees of 1%, it will give me -11.79%.

Comment: I have a few questions because I don't understand what you want to achieve. Weren't you supposing that the gross depreciation was -10% in the first place as an example? If yes, then wouldn't you use your formula $\frac{\text{sold } - M}{M}$ to get $\frac{45 - 50}{50} = -0.1$? Same idea with how you got 11.79%? And what do you mean by 2 fees of 1%?

Comment: Thank you @Accelerator. I want to obtain -11.79%, the net loss, without having to calculate the $sold$ value (which required the initial amount and asset prices to be calculated). I suppose it should be possible to compute the net profit/loss solely based on the gross price increase/decrease percentage (-10%) and fees (-1% * 2).

Comment: I never studied finance, but the only ideas I have are: (gross income) - (expenses) = (net income); (revenue) - (cost of goods sold) - (expenses) = (net income). I got that from https://www.patriotsoftware.com/blog/accounting/net-income/ after a quick Google search. Other than that, I'm not sure how you can calculate the net profit/loss by your idea.